# error NullPointerException con VideoView

Tags: android, recyclerview, videoview

Tengo una clase adaptadora con una lista de videos y necesito poder reproducirlos en un VideoView según el usuario elija, me da un error 'NullPointerException' al  intentar cargar el video en el reproductor, he corregido la referencia al videoview en el layout pero no consigo quitar el error...

AdapterDatos.java

```
public ViewHolderDatos onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int 
      viewType) {   

   LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate
            (R.layout.item_list,null,false);

    return new ViewHolderDatos(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolderDatos holder, int 
 position) {

    holder.asignarDatos(listDatos.get(position));
    final int pos = position;

    if (posicionmarcada==position){
        listDatos.get(position);
    }

    holder.dato.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        posicionmarcada = pos;
   int rawID = 
  context.getResources().getIdentifier(listDatos.get(position),"raw", 
  context.getPackageName());
            String path = "android.resource://" + 
  context.getPackageName()+"/"+rawID;

            holder.videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
            holder.videoView.start();
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
public class ViewHolderDatos extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    VideoView videoView;
    TextView dato;

    public ViewHolderDatos(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        dato=itemView.findViewById(R.id.idDato);
    }
```

Error:

```
 2020-11-23 19:49:38.931 12874-12874/com.example.m08_act03 
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.m08_act03, PID: 12874
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void 
 android.widget.VideoView.setVideoURI(android.net.Uri)' on a null object 
 reference
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu `VideoView` no existe en el layout que Carga el `Adapter` en el método  `onCreateViewHolder()` o no estas obteniendo la referencia.

Debes asegurar agregar que se encuentre el `VideoView` en el layout y obtener su referencia, ejemplo:

```
public class ViewHolderDatos extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        VideoView videoView;
        ...
        ...
        public ViewHolderDatos(View itemView) {
            //*Obtiene referencia de VideoView en Layout.  
            videoView = (VideoView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.videoview);
            ...
            ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hola Jorge, ya tengo una referencia al VideoView no he conseguido quitar el error, sabes que puede estar pasando?